# Why i need to use the const function in the Less Traits

Tags: c++

why i need to use the const function in the less traits? 
for example, why i must use const in Age or ID member function.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
public:
    Person(int id, string name, int age):m_iID(id), m_strName(name), m_iAge(age){};
    int Age() const {return m_iAge;}
    int ID() const {return m_iID;}
    void Display();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Person& person);
private:
    int m_iID;
    string m_strName;
    int m_iAge;

};
void Person::Display()
{
    cout<<m_iID<<" "<<m_strName<<" "<<m_iAge<<endl;
}
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Person& person)
{
    out<<person.m_iID<<" "<<person.m_strName<<" "<<person.m_iAge<<endl;
    return out;
}

int SumPersonAge(int iSumAge, Person& person)
{
    return iSumAge + person.Age();
}
template <typename Type>
void Display(Type t1)
{
    cout<<t1<<endl;
}

class LessPerson
{
public:
    template <typename Type>
    bool operator()(Type& t1, Type& t2)
    {
        return t1.ID() < t2.ID();
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<Person, LessPerson> s1;
    Person p1(1234, "Roger", 23);
    Person p2(1235, "Razor", 24);
    s1.insert(p1);
    s1.insert(p2);
    for_each(s1.begin(), s1.end(), Display<Person>);
}
```

if i remove the const the keyword in Age or ID function, the compiler will report me Error  cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Person' to 'Person &'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that the set will pass two const reference to `Person` objects to your comparator, and you cannot call a non-const function on a const variable.

You might be surprised as there seems not to be any `const` in the declaration of the functor:

```
struct LessPerson
{
    template <typename Type>
    bool operator()(Type& t1, Type& t2)
    {
        return t1.ID() < t2.ID();
    }
};
```

But there is, it is just not explicit in the code. Inside the `set` implementation there are two `const Person&` references (call them `r1`, `r2`) and a `LessPerson` comparator (call it `compare`) and the code does something in the lines of `if ( comparator(r1,r2) )`. The compiler finds the templated `operator()` and tries to infer the types ending up with the type substitution: `Type == const Person`.

Why does the `set` use const references rather than plain modifiable references? Well, that is a different issue. The set is implemented as a sorted balanced tree, with each node containing the *key*. Now because a change in the key would break the *order* invariant, the keys are themselves `const` objects, ensuring that you cannot break the invariants.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me where i can find these reference about the detail of invoking comparator in set?

Answer (score 1):

That `const` keyword means that the function does not modify its object, `this`. Only `const` functions may be called from `const` objects. So, the compiler is telling you that you are trying to call a non-const member function from a const object.

You appear to be avoiding the `const` keyword, but it creeps in when the library calls your template function:

```
template <typename Type>
bool operator()(Type& t1, Type& t2)
{
    return t1.ID() < t2.ID();
}
```

`Type` is passed as `const Person`.

`const` is not easy to get rid of without cheating, and it will always creep in. It's better to go with the flow and add `const` everywhere you take a reference that doesn't change an object (which is most of them).

Answer (score 0):

Because the type passed to `LessPerson` is `const Person`.

So basically, `LessPerson` is roughly

```
class LessPerson     
{ 
public:
  bool operator()(const Person& t1, const Person& t2)
  {
     return t1.ID() < t2.ID();
  }
};
```

You can't call non-const methods on const objects. It's a rule of C++.